# PHP responses getting messed up due to host's ads

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, response, web-hosting

I have a swf website that requests PHP files, and acts depending on the response it got from the PHP file.

It works fine in local, but the problem is when I upload it to my Web host.

The host, for some reason, adds an ad to the response which looks something like this:

```
<!-- Start abc123 -->
Free stuff
ads
<-- End abc 123 -->
```

The problem is that my swf catches that as part of the PHP response, which is really messing things up.

So, how do I prevent my swf from catching that part, **or** how do I prevent my response from getting "ad-ed"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but it looks like you don't usually mark answers as accepted. People are more likely to answer your questions if you have a reputation for accepting an answer so they get credit.

Comment: Well, it's mostly because in most of my questions with no accepted answers, I didn't find an answer that helped me/worked for me. I mostly wait a while before accepting an answer in hopes of getting better answers. But, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of testing different ideas, I finally came up with a solution that will let PHP send back to the swf and **ignore** anything other than the response.

I thought I'd share it so it can be easier for for others in the future:

For each of your PHP files, add `&bogus='bogus'` at the end of any Print or Echo statement.

**Example:**

```
//at the end of your PHP
print "result=Success";
```

Switch to:

```
print "result=Success&bogus='bogus'";
```

That way, any ads or extra sent will be appended to `'bogus'` and it will not get in the way of your code!~

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is, assuming you have full control over your swf site, edit that code to look for and filter out anything between `<!-- Start abc123 -->` and `<-- End abc 123 -->`.

Alternatively, if their ad comment is dynamic/hard to look for, you could add your own static comment and look for the content in between.

There are some [free hosts](http://www.000webhost.com/) that don't add ads.

Comment: Well, I've tried replacing those lines whenever it occurs, but that method is sometimes unreliable, because the ad's might change. PS: That's actually the site I'm using xD

Comment: That's funny, their site says they don't have ads, although I have no personal experience. Glad you found a solution to your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help! And yes, at first I didn't think they had ads either, I didn't get them until after a couple of days.